# bash, cURL to links specified in file

Tags: bash, curl, grep

I need something like that: in one file I have links, for example:

```
file 1

link 1
link 2
link 3
```

And bash script should enter all links and copy-paste data from there. I need only data which is followed by "example" string, ex:

```
example 15-20
example 14-21
```

I need 15-20 and 14-21 as a result. I was thinking about grep function, but the main issue is how to enter all links from file 1 (link 1, link 2, link 3)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk for example:

```
awk '$1=="example"{print $2}' file
```

Or `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP 'example \K.+' file
```